# Gradle skip idea module generation

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a project setup that is as follows

```
Project A
|
|-Sub-Project B
|-Sub-Project C
| |
| \-src
|   |
|   |-Sub-Project D
|   \-Sub-Project E
\-Sub-Project F
```

In order to get the project to build and Idea modules created I need to put a build.gradle file at each level, however I dont really want idea modules created for Project C and the child src directory. Is there a way to suppress these modules?

Also is there a way to specify a group for idea modules?

Comment: The easiest solution is to adapt `settings.gradle` so that `Sub-Project C` and `src` don't become Gradle subprojects. I don't understand the latter question (group).

Comment: But I will still need a build.gradle file in those directories?

I was hoping to be able to remove those directories from the Intellij project view. In Intellij you can group projects together in logical views, I was hoping that there was a way to specify this grouping so the ipr generated by gradle had those groups.

Comment: I found this post (http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/skip_root_module_in_idea_project) which does pretty much all I need to do except correctly create the ipr file. I see the project how I would like to see it but Project C and src are still added as projects and Intellij gives an error that it cannot find the iml files.

Project C and src are not mentioned in the settings.gradle file. How can I stop the idea plugin adding src and Project C into the ipr file?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to the question of not adding the projects to the ipr file. Adding the following to my top level build.gradle file only adds projects where ideaModule.enabled == true.

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    gradle.rootProject {
        ideaModule.enabled = false
        idea {
            project {
                modulesToInclude = subprojects.findAll {it.ideaModule.enabled == true}
                modules = modulesToInclude.idea.module
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create `Sub-Project D` directly in the `Sub-Project C` directory (without a `src` directory). You can also omit `build.gradle` in `Sub-Project C`. Idea 13 imports that structure without any problems. Just remember to add only the **real** subprojects to the `settings.gradle`:

```
include 'Sub-Project B', 'Sub-Project D', 'Sub-Project E', ...
```

Comment: I am not able to change the directory structure. If this was possible I would have gone for that as it is the easiest option.

Thanks