# Control automatic creation of IDEA modules from Gradle sourceSets in 2016.1?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-idea-2016

Starting with [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#gradle), IDEA automatically creates IntelliJ modules from Gradle SourceSets ([link](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2016/03/gradle-goodness-source-sets-as-intellij.html)). While I recognize that this was a major step forward for many reasons, it is also a major change for existing projects which relied on IDEA being source set agnostic. I currently get over 50 new modules that I don't want ...

Do you know of a way to restore IntelliJ's old behavior?

Is there a way to control how modules are created from source sets, for example by excluding a sourceset?

I already checked the [Gradle IDEA plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) but could not find a solution. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21240161/1005481) but it seems to apply only to multi-module projects, not to the source set problem.
I am using Gradle 2.12 and, obviously, IDEA 2016.1.

Comment: I do also have a problem with the new behaviour. We do code coverage analysis and the plugins (`scoverage`) creates two additional `sourceSets`. This `main` works fine after import but the `test` source are not recognised properly. After I delete the additional modules from `Project Structure > Modules` everything works fine again.

Comment: That's not a solution to this problem but I didn't found another way. Problem, after refreshing the gradle project the additional modules reappear!
We don't use the `idea` plugin for gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no way of controlling the automatic creation of modules based on projects `sourceSets`.

There are quite a lot issues regarding this problem:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153231

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154014

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153264

**Edit:**

Since IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 (I think) there is a new option "Create separate module per source set" on "Import Project from Gradle" dialog:

[image]

Comment: Just saw it. Will update the answer as soon as there is a release and a screenshot with the option.